# Java Process takes more memory and Machine stop working

Tags: 14.04, java, ruby, rvm

I am new to Linux, I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS, But suddenly my machine stop working.I run

```
$ free -m
```

and get results

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7897       4318       3578        313         84       2054
-/+ buffers/cache:       2179       5717
Swap:         8013          0       8013
```

and when I run `top -c` i get

```
15001 qi34      20   0 1681144 133824  11896 S  63.0  1.7   0:29.43         /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/home/qi34/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 + 
15013 qi34      20   0 1681144 133288  11892 S  60.4  1.6   0:29.21         /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/home/qi34/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 + 
15087 qi34      20   0 1681144 124008  11936 S  57.7  1.5   0:28.88         /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/home/qi34/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 + 
14290 qi34      20   0 2632636 381032  13040 S  53.7  4.7   1:05.42         /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/home/qi34/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 + 
14349 qi34      20   0 2632636 374516  13052 S  53.4  4.6   1:05.22         /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/home/qi34/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 + 
14348 qi34      20   0 2632636 377124  13048 S  53.1  4.7   1:03.12         /usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/home/qi34/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.16 +
```

This process takes utilize more memory.I run `killall java` but doesn't solve my problem. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to get all the Java processes

```
ps -aux |grep java| cut -c10-15
```

and then kill them using

```
kill -9 process id from the above command
```

Now find out what is the culprit program. Before installing anything - try to go thru the release notes. You need to uninstall it and also delete the directories created by this culprit program. If you can provide more details about this program then specific answer can be provided.

Comment: I have done the above command, but again the process run.What are details you want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **pkill** option? pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout and will instantly kill any process matching the specified process name unless the process is performing a syscall. Here, try this

```
pkill -9 java
```

Will attempt to instantly shutdow all processes with the name matching ***java***
then you can check again like this

```
ps aux | grep java
```

Let me know how it goes.!

Comment: Its temporarily solve problem.I uninstall jruby from rvm then the process stop working and system works well.But after I install jruby again and Its creates the process again.

Comment: How many times are you installing jruby?

Comment: one time I have installed.

Comment: Let me get this straight, everytime you kill it it restarts.. is that what your saying?

Answer (score 0):

Its my fault the above process running because of cron  jobs.In my rails application I have run cron jobs, thats why the process are creating.